# Better understanding of cosine similarity

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, cosine-similarity

I am doing a little research on text mining and data mining. I need more help in understanding cosine similarity. I have read about it and notice that all of the given examples on the internet is using tf-idf before computing it through cosine-similarity.

My question

Is it possible to calculate cosine similarity just by using highest frequency distribution from a text file which will be the dataset. Most of the videos and tutorials that i go through has tf-idf ran before inputting it's data into cosine similarity, if no, what other types of equation/algorithm that can be input into cosine similarity?

2.Why is normalization used with tf-idf to compute cosine similarity? (can i do it without normalization?) Cosine similarity are computed from normalization of tf-idf output. Why is normalization needed?

3.What cosine similarity actually does to the weights of tf-idf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand question 1.

2. TF-IDF weighting is a weighting scheme that worked well for lots of people on real data (think Lucene search). But the theoretical foundations of it are a bit weak. In particular, everybody seems to be using a slightly different version of it... and yes, it is weights + cosine similarity. In practise, you may want to try e.g. Okapi BM25 weighting instead, though.
3. I do not undestand this question either. Angular similarity is beneficial because the *length* of the text has less influence than with other distances. Furthermore, sparsity can be nicely exploitet. As for the weights, IDF is a heuristic with only loose statistical arguments: frequent words are more likely to occur at random, and thus should have less weight.

Maybe you can try to rephrase your questions so I can fully understand them. Also search for related questions such as these: [Cosine similarity and tf-idf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255835/cosine-similarity-and-tf-idf?rq=1) and 
[Better text documents clustering than tf/idf and cosine similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537722/better-text-documents-clustering-than-tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity?rq=1)

Comment: For Question 
1) I have watched tutorials and read some documents on cosine similarity, all of them used tf-idf's output value from a set of data to be passed into cosine similarity equation. What i wanted to ask here is that, is it possible to do cosine similarity with frequency distribution instead of tf-idf's output?

2)Why is normalization needed to be added into tf-idf equation when calculating for cosine similarity? which is ||x||2 

I do understand  that tf-idf is for weights

Comment: sorry for the poor question. already re-edited the questions. pretty new in this topic.

Comment: tf is term frequency... yes, you can do tf only, but tf-idf works better because it puts less weight on frequent words. Normalization - look up the definition of cosine angle... that is math.

Comment: this will be a little off topic, i have seen your profile and you have answered some question on k-mean. Can k-mean used to calculate strings? For instance, to cluster keywords into categories, from a database of texts.From my understanding it's only possible to use integers in k-mean and by sorting 4 keywords the centroids will divided equally on 4 edges returning an inaccurate result.

Comment: K-means can only be used on float vectors. Because it must compute *means*. You can use spherical k-means on documents, but not on keywords. And IMHO, it doesn't really work well.